# How to give the user the ability to control photo animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, photo

I have a general question about creating a photo which can be animated.

My example is if you take a computer you could do a 360 degree view of the computer and giving the user the ability to click and drag to open and close the computer.

I was wondering if there is some specific way on how to animate a photo to do something like that in `html`, `css`, and some script language and if there is a specific term for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be using HTML canvas and do 3d animation (using javascript, no css used in this case). You will need to detect mouse event , rendering, animation frame , etc to accomplish it. this one is an example to your problem

http://www.kevs3d.co.uk/dev/phoria/

Try to learn canvas by googling. you can try search canvas 2d animation first, or you can just directly search 3d canvas animation.

Comment: I'm thinking of using babylon.js, a friend of mine told me about it and has some experience using it.

Comment: Yes, using library is recommended. If someone else already made it, then no need to make it from scratch. From what I see, I think babylon.js is pretty good to use. But I still think you need basic canvas animation if you want to understand more.